# non-stateless model in web app?

Tags: web-services, machine-learning

Imagine a small machine-learning web application:

```
users submit the subject of a news atrticle
server would tell what category(e.g. sport or politics) it belongs to
if the server answered wrongly, user can submit a correct category
```

Most machine-learning algorithm have to remember their states so that they can incrementally improve the models. It's very inefficient to re-calculate the model every time the server receives a request.

But web application is based on stateless model. The only persistence layer is database. So how to implement those non-stateless models in web application? Is the best practice to serialize its internal states and store it in database?

btw I'm using `Rails` but I guess most of the web frameworks are stateless.

Comment: And what about HTTP session? BTW I don't know *any* web framework that is stateless (see above).

Answer (score 0):

The web is stateless so it makes sense that web frameworks are also stateless. So you'll have to store the state somewhere on the server; a good candidate is the database. Many websites have large databases so it shouldn't be a problem to store many states of the machine-learning algorithm in the database too.